# WordPress pagination not working on custom post types and taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Trying to paginate custom post types by custom taxonomy terms and default posts by category but it does not working. I'm novice to WordPress, I did lots of googling and didn't find a detailed solution to solve my issue.

If anyone knows please share your answer, it's really appreciated.

Note: I created a custom theme.

Here is my **taxonomy-product_category.php** page code:

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="container-fluid pages">
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 10%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <?php $term = get_queried_object();
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($term->taxonomy);

            ?>
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4><?php echo 'محصولات : '.$term-  >name;?></h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php

                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array('post_type'=>'my_product',
                        'taxonomy'=>$taxonomy->name,
                        'posts_per_page'=> 1,
                        'term'=>$term->slug,
                        'paged'=>$paged);

                    $query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($query->have_posts()) {
                    while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('featured');
                            } ?>
                            <div class="caption caption-content">
                                <h3 class="product-name"><?php the_title();  ?></h3>
                                <p class="text-muted">
                                    <!-- <strong>نویسنده:</strong> <?php     //the_author();?>  -->
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp; تاریخ: <?php the_date(); ?> </p>
                                <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="price-box">
                                        <i class="fa fa-  circle">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>قیمت:
                                        <?php if (the_field('price') == '')     {
                                            // echo "00.00";
                                        } else {
                                            the_field('price');
                                        } ?>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;
                }
                else {
                    echo '<h3>هیچ موردی درین بخش یافت نشد.</h3>';
                }
                ?>

                <!-- pagination here -->
                <p>

                        <nav>
                            <?php if ( function_exists( 'custom_pagination'   ) ) {
                                custom_pagination($custom_query-  >max_num_pages,"", $paged);
                            } ?>
                        </nav>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
        <?php get_sidebar();  ?>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

When I click on next page it redirects me to index page where the url is still:
   **http://localhost/goldsotre/product_category/ring/page/2/**
**Custom_pagination function:**

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
}
global $paged;
if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
}
if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
}
$pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
);

$paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
    echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
    echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing the space, also please paste your custom pagination function

$custom_query-  >max_num_pages to $custom_query->max_num_pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chance is `posts_per_page` got overridden by **Blog pages show at most** value.

I assume you're using the `paginate_link()` function, try this in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query)
{
    if ($query->is_tax('product_category')) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
    }
});
```

Make sure `product_category` is the taxonomy of the archive page. [This article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type) maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I use below function instead of that I can see the pagination links but not working, when clicking on the **next** link, I get 404 page.

```
$big = 999999999; 
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $query->max_num_pages ) );
```